# Display sponsor using if else , does not show PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get a website to be highlighted on my toplist, using if else statement. When I inspect the element of a server, that is supposed to be a sponsor website, it doesn't show up as "sponsor site" css, it's still coming through as glossed ( sponsor = 0 ).  I'm not sure if I'm actually checking if the website is a sponsor or not?

```
<?php
require_once('mysql_connect.php');

$query  =   "SELECT id, name, banner, description, sponsor, votes, hits FROM websites ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 50";
$result =   mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
// Rank counter
$rank = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    //it would wrap your text upto 20 characters 
    $wrappedText = wordwrap(substr($row['description'], 0, 200), 55, "<br />\n", true);

    if(sponsor == 0){
        echo '<tbody>
    <tr class="server glossed site">
        <td class="rank hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        '.$rank.'</td>
        <td class="description"><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['name'].'<br /><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" rel="no_follow" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['banner'].'" width="470" height="60"></a></p></a><br><p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.
        $wrappedText.'</p></td>
        <td class="votes hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.$row['votes'].'</td>
    </tr>';
    } else {
        echo '<tbody>
    <tr class="server sponsor site">
        <td class="rank hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        '.$rank.'</td>
        <td class="description"><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['name'].'<br /><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" rel="no_follow" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['banner'].'" width="470" height="60"></a></p></a><br><p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.
        $wrappedText.'</p></td>
        <td class="votes hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.$row['votes'].'</td>
    </tr>';
    }
$rank++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably also seeing a PHP error. Either way, your while statement is kind of looping through your query result as it is an array therefore, you have to change

```
if(sponsor == 0){
```

to

```
if ($row['sponsor'] == 0) {
```

This should give you the expected result.

Comment: Hey Junkystu, may i ask for one more thing?

Comment: http://rs-list.com/vote.php?id=74  , when i try to vote, it gives me a sql syntax error?

 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1     here is my vote.php  full page code: http://pastebin.com/adCVLqWN

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to create another question for that one and post more information such as the query that you are attempting to run whilst making it clear that you are using MariaDB

Comment: No problem , 90 minute wait, :(

Comment: @KIXEYE Also, don't forget to mark this question as answered